# Add dynamic text GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to add text to the video stream using GPUImage, however no text is showing. My filters are all working great however I can't seem to chain my text filter into the correct order. I want the text to be under my custom filter so the custom filter is having an effect on the text.

```
    videoCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
mCurrentImage = [NPFilterBuilder getTextureOverlay];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:mCurrentImage smoothlyScaleOutput:NO];
[sourcePicture processImage];

customFilter = [NPFilterBuilder getFilter];
[videoCamera addTarget:cropFilter];
[cropFilter addTarget:customFilter atTextureLocation:0];
[sourcePicture addTarget:customFilter atTextureLocation:1];

[customFilter addTarget:mViewCameraPreview];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update element, may be it will help you.

```
__unsafe_unretained GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElementInput = uiElementInput;
[filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
[weakUIElementInput update];
}];
```